# Исправьте грамматическую ошибку в предложении

Tags: предлоги, управление, местоимения

> Он беспокоится за того, кого он любит.

Ошибка в употреблении местоимения "того", необходимо ее исправить и записать правильный ответ.

Comment: Подумайте, как ещё можно сказать. Это не сложно (выполнить это д/з).

Comment: Это не д/з. Это бракованное задание - ошибся составитель.

Answer (score 2):

А и нету ошибки в задании! Задание само с ошибкой! Оно хотело подсунуть нам "за тем", но промахнулось - написало один из двух верных вариантов:

*1). Он беспокоится за того, кого он любит.*

*2). Он беспокоится о том, кого он любит.*

А вот "Он беспокоится за тем, кого он любит" и было бы грубейшей грамматической (т. е. воспринимаемой на слух) ошибкой. В лучшем случае - диалектизмом.